# MySQL count(*) returning 0 even though I used IFNULL and COALESCE

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

USE adventureWorks4mysql;

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.city, count(a.city) as "City Count", emp.Gender as Gender, emp.VacationHours as VacationHours, 
(select  if(count(*) is null,0, count(*))
FROM address aa
inner join employeeaddress empad on aa.AddressID = empad.AddressID
inner join employee emp on empad.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
where MaritalStatus = 'M' and aa.city = a.city
group by aa.City) as married,

(select ifnull(count(*),0)
FROM address aa
inner join employeeaddress empad on aa.AddressID = empad.AddressID
inner join employee emp on empad.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
where MaritalStatus = 'S' and aa.city = a.city
group by aa.City)  as single

FROM address a

inner join employeeaddress empad on a.AddressID = empad.AddressID

inner join employee emp on empad.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID

group by a.City;
```

returns the following:

```
'Bellevue', '36', 'F', '5', '22', '14'
'Berlin', '1', 'F', '35', NULL, '1'
'Bordeaux', '1', 'M', '34', NULL, '1'
'Bothell', '13', 'M', '9', '7', '6'
'Calgary', '1', 'M', '33', '1', NULL
'Cambridge', '2', 'F', '37', '2', NULL
'Carnation', '5', 'M', '77', '4', '1'
'Detroit', '1', 'M', '38', NULL, '1'
'Duluth', '1', 'F', '24', NULL, '1'
'Duvall', '10', 'F', '80', '3', '7'
'Edmonds', '25', 'M', '84', '16', '9'
'Everett', '18', 'M', '42', '11', '7'
'Gold Bar', '5', 'M', '92', '3', '2'
'Index', '5', 'F', '61', '3', '2'
'Issaquah', '15', 'M', '70', '4', '11'
'Kenmore', '12', 'F', '86', '5', '7'
'Kent', '1', 'F', '5', '1', NULL
'Melbourne', '1', 'F', '36', NULL, '1'
'Memphis', '1', 'M', '29', '1', NULL
'Minneapolis', '1', 'M', '48', NULL, '1'
'Monroe', '14', 'M', '21', '4', '10'
'Nevada', '1', 'F', '27', '1', NULL
'Newport Hills', '7', 'M', '44', '2', '5'
'Ottawa', '1', 'M', '31', '1', NULL
'Portland', '1', 'F', '22', NULL, '1'
'Redmond', '21', 'M', '2', '11', '10'
'Renton', '17', 'M', '6', '12', '5'
'Sammamish', '17', 'F', '31', '6', '11'
'San Francisco', '2', 'M', '16', '2', NULL
'Seattle', '44', 'F', '82', '21', '23'
'Snohomish', '10', 'M', '88', '3', '7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all clear about you desired result, but is you are attempting to count cities, then I suggest you use "conditional aggregates" instead of your current approach, like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.city
  , COUNT( a.city )   AS "City Count"
  , count(CASE WHEN maritalstatus = 'M' THEN a.city END) AS married
  , count(CASE WHEN maritalstatus = 'S' THEN a.city END) AS single 
FROM address a
INNER JOIN employeeaddress empad ON a.addressid = empad.addressid
INNER JOIN employee emp ON empad.employeeid = emp.employeeid
GROUP BY
    a.city;
```

Note how the case expression is INSIDE the aggregate function `COUNT` - hence the term "conditional aggregates" e.g. for singles, if there is a singe status then count that address other wise just ignore that row. nb `COUNT` does not increment if a value is null.

Please also note that you are only grouping by the single column `city`. If you really want more result rows because of `gender` and `vacationhours` then also use those columns in the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT 
    a.city
  , emp.gender        AS Gender
  , emp.vacationhours AS VacationHours
  , COUNT( a.city )   AS "City Count"
  , count(CASE WHEN maritalstatus = 'M' THEN a.city END) AS married
  , count(CASE WHEN maritalstatus = 'S' THEN a.city END) AS single 
FROM address a
INNER JOIN employeeaddress empad ON a.addressid = empad.addressid
INNER JOIN employee emp ON empad.employeeid = emp.employeeid
GROUP BY
    a.city
  , emp.gender 
  , emp.vacationhours 
;
```